What is Hinduism say about Gluttony and Sloth?
Well, we known, Kama (lust), Krodha (anger), Lobha (greed), Mada (pride), Moha (delude), and Matsarya (envy) are deadly sins from our Hinduism.
But, several days ago, i have learned that gluttony and sloth are also a bad thing (not exactly from Hinduism, but from others). But, what is opininion of our Hinduism about gluttony and sloth? Does any scriptures mention them?


नात्यश्नतस्तु योगोऽस्ति न चैकान्तमनश्नतः ।
न चातिस्वप्नशीलस्य जाग्रतो नैव चार्जुन ॥१६॥

There is no possibility of one's becoming a yogī, O Arjuna, if one
eats too much, or eats too little, sleeps too much or does not sleep
enough. (Bhagavad Gita 6.16).

